# VS Code - How to use JSDoc to document a prototype methods and property

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I've a piece of code like this:

```
//line 0

/**
 * Constructor of class Person
 * @class
 * @constructor
 * @param {string} name Name of person
 * @param {string} surname Surname of person 
 * @param {number} age Age of person 
 */
function Person(name, surname, age){
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.age = age;
}


/** Optional for my project, MISSING JSDOC */
Person.prototype = {
    //..somethings..

    /** MISSING JSDOC */
    talk: function(){
        //..somethings..
    }, 

    /** MISSING JSDOC */
    walk: function(){
        //..somethings..
    }, 

    /** MISSING JSDOC */
    foo: function(){
        //..somethings..
        p.bar();
        //..somethings..
    }
};

/**
 * A shortcut to access to {@link Person} methods' more easly
 * @type {Object} p 
 */
var p = Person.prototype;

//something else
```

But I don't know how to comment the .prototype object to see, with IntelliSense, the description and possibly type of the properties or methods.
I've tried before to searching on StackOverflow and on other sites, but nothing was realy helpfull.
Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use @memberof tag identifier. Please see documentation and example of usage: [JSDoc @memberof](https://jsdoc.app/tags-memberof.html)

You may want to use @alias as well to exclude "prototype" from your documentation. The example and documentation of usage: [JSDoc @alias](https://jsdoc.app/tags-alias.html)

Comment: @memberof doesn't seam to work with vscode salsa/intellisense and is not listed in the typescript suported jsdoc tags